# Control plot layout in foodweb plot from mvbutils R-package

Tags: r, tree

I would like to visualize how functions in my own R package depend on each other. For this purpose I use the `foodweb()` function from the `mvbutils` package.

I can get the right functional dependencies out without a problem but the plot looks a bit messy, with lines crossing each other and function names not aligned vertically or horizontally.

Is there a way to control the layout of the plot similar to the way this works in the `igraph` package?

#### Example

```
dirPath <- "~/dev/stackoverflow/46910042"
setwd(dirPath)

## Download example Package
urlPackage <- "https://github.com/kbroman/qtlcharts/archive/master.zip"
download.file(urlPackage, destfile = "master.zip")
unzip("./master.zip", exdir = dirPath, overwrite = TRUE)

## Install or load mcbutils
if (!require(mvbutils)) install.packages("mvbutils")
thefiles = list.files(path = "./qtlcharts-master/R/", full.names = TRUE)
thefiles
## Now we load all the package files into memory, so we can have 
## foodweb generate a map of the package functions.
sapply(thefiles, source)

## Generate plot 
par(mar = rep(0.1, 4))
foodweb(border = TRUE, boxcolor = "pink", lwd = 1.5, cex = 0.8)
```

#### Plot Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Michael,

One option is to look behind the curtains of foodweb. The `mvbutils::foodweb` function returns an object of (S3) class `foodweb`. This has three components:

- **funmat** a matrix of 0s and 1s showing what (row) calls what (column). The dimnames are the function names.
- **x** shows the x-axis location of the centre of each function’s name in the display, in par("usr") units
- **level** shows the y-axis location of the centre of each function’s name in the display, in par("usr") units.

thus one approach we can take is to call `foodweb` but tell it not to create a plot rather return a `foodweb` object. This then allows us to manipulate the data directory or via `graphics::plot()` externally of the defaults provided by the `mvbutils::foodweb()` function.

***Why?*** Well, to do what you suggest my sense is three options exist:

- You can either play with `mvbutils::foodweb()` parameters.
- Work with data structure returned with another plotting package.
- Use `graphics::par()` and `graphics::plot` to manipulate the plot size and attributes of the `foodweb` structure returned.

It would be great to know your preference. Excluding, that my sense was to provide a base example:

#### Plot Package Example

In the case of using `graphics::plot`, you need to go look at how you manipulate `graphics:par`. `par()` allows you to set or query graphical parameters. For example, if we want to clean up the function plot you might choose to modify the [grahics::par()](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/graphics/versions/3.4.0/topics/par) `fin` parameter to increase the figure region dimensions, (width, height), in inches. A simple example but my sense it helps map out and demonstrate the options available to you.

```
## Generate plot
if (!require(qtlcharts)) install.packages("qtlcharts")

## Here we specify `asNamespace` to get the package internals
fw <- foodweb( where = asNamespace( "qtlcharts"),
               plotting = FALSE,
               )
#Display foodweb structure
str(fw)

# Expand plot figure region dimensions...
par(fin = c(9.9,7))
# Plot fw strucuture
plot(fw, 
     border = TRUE, 
     expand.xbox = 1,
     boxcolor = "pink", lwd = 1.5, cex = 0.8)
```

#### Plot Output example

Note that the function names are not spaced out. Note I cut the top and bottom white of plot here. In this case, you can play with the par constraints such as margin to get the plot you want.

[image]

### Pruning your plot

Another option within the constraints of `mvbutils::foodweb` is to use the `prune` and `rprune` option to simplify your plots. These are super poweful and useful especially the regular expression version.

```
if (!require(qtlcharts)) install.packages("qtlcharts")
fw <- foodweb( where = asNamespace( "qtlcharts"),
               plotting = FALSE)

str(fw)
par(fin = c(9.9,7))
plot(fw, 
     border = TRUE, 
     expand.xbox = 1,
     boxcolor = "pink", lwd = 1.5, cex = 0.8)

fw <- foodweb( where = asNamespace( "qtlcharts"),
               rprune = "convert_", ## search on `convert_` to negate use `~convert_`
               plotting = FALSE)
str(fw)
par(fin = c(9.9,7))
plot(fw, 
     border = TRUE, 
     expand.xbox = 1,
     boxcolor = "pink", lwd = 1.5, cex = 0.8)
```

[image]

Hoping the above information points you in the right direction.
T.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the fact that there are many data, connections etc, the plot is squeezed in order to fit in the screen, hence it becomes messy.

What I would suggest is to save it in a PDF or PNG with  big enough width and Height and then you can zoom in. This will save you a lot of time. 
E.G.

```
## Generate plot 
pdf( "mygraph.pdf", width = 50, height = 80 )
par(mar = rep(0.1, 4))
foodweb(border = TRUE, boxcolor = "pink", lwd = 1.5, cex = 0.8)
dev.off()
```

In addition, you can play with the plot options of `foodweb`.

Hope it helps.